# Reproduce lhs2tex’s code indentation in LaTeX

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, tabbing, lhs2tex

The preprocessor lhs2tex has a very neat way of aligning code. Consider this snippet:

```
let t1 = foo x
in  let g x =  if x > 10
               then  t1
               else  let t2 = bar x
                     in  let h y =  if y > 10
                                    then  g (t2 y)
                                    else  h (y+1)
                         in h 1 x
    in g 1 2
```

It detects the desired indentation based on more than two spaces, and uses (I believe) nested tabbing environments to produce this:

[image: nicely formatted code]

Note how although a proportional font is used, the vertical alignment is great.

Is there a way to reproduce this conveniently in LaTeX? Maybe even with listings (for which I have configured syntax highlighting properly)?

Comment: @kosmikus, maybe you know something here :-)

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's what you're looking for, but the `listings` package can perform *some* code formatting; see section 5.6 of the manual.

Comment: Here, 5.6 is about line numbers. But if you refer to the various flexible layouting algorithms – none of them can match’s lhs2tex’s capabilities.

Comment: I was referring to *5.6, Automatic formatting* (at least in v1.5e of the doc), but you're right: what you can do with `listings` in that respect pales in comparison to `lhs2tex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I approximated it using lhs2tex’s `polytable` package directly, and I now get the desired output with:

```
\begin{acode}
\> !let t1 = foo x \\
\> !in \> !let g x = \> !if x > 10 \\
\>     \>            \> !then \> t1 \\
\>     \>            \> !else \> !let t2 = bar x \\
\>     \>            \>       \> !in  \> !let h y = \> !if y > 10 \\
\>     \>            \>       \>      \>            \> !then \> g (t2 y) \\
\>     \>            \>       \>      \>            \> !else \> h (y+1) \\
\>     \>            \>       \>      \> !in h 1 x \\
\>     \> !in g 1 2. \\
\end{acode}
```

by using these definitions:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`!=\active
\gdef\activateexclamationmark{%    note the global \gdef
  \catcode`!=\active%
  \def!##1 {\hkw{##1} }%
}
\endgroup

\def\acode{%
\begingroup%
\activateexclamationmark%
\sffamily%
\ptboxed%
\defaultcolumn{@{}l@{ }}%
\ignorespaces%
}
\def\endacode{%
\endptboxed%
\endgroup%
}

\newcommand{\hkw}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
```

The `catcode` stuff is to introduce `!` as a marker for keywords – a low-noise approximation to real syntax highlighting, but I could not think of a way to get both syntax highlighting *and* be able to insert my tab markers.

I still wonder if it would be possible to define an environment that reads its contents verbatim and replaces every stretch of two or more spaces with `\={n}`, where `n` is the column of the last space.